# Blank view in android with open gl(AsyncTask)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, opengl-es-2.0

I am using Open GL ES 2.0 to perform certain effects on bitmaps, now if i load a bitmap directly on UI thread it takes alot of time, hence im using AsyncTask....

**Problem:-**

When i use AsyncTask,all i get is a blank/black texture screen,without asynctask it display the bitmap after 7-8 seconds depending on the size.

I did check out many other related questions with similar title,but their problems seem different.

**Following is the code:-**

```
    public class TinypostFilters extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

                private Uri myuri;
                int dw;
                int dh;

                private GLSurfaceView mEffectView;
                private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
                private EffectContext mEffectContext;
                private Effect mEffect;
                private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
                private int mImageWidth;
                private int mImageHeight;
                private boolean mInitialized = false;


                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tinypost_filters);

                    /*
                     * Initialize renderer and set it to only render when explicitly
                     * requested with the RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY option.
                     */

                    mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
                    mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
                    mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
                    mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
                    mCurrentEffect = R.id.none;

                }



    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mInitialized) {
            // Only need to do this once
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
            mTexRenderer.init();

            loadTextures();

            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            // if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            initEffect();
            //applyEffect();
        }
        renderResult();
    }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
                    if (mTexRenderer != null) {
                        mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
                }


           private void loadTextures() {
                    // Generate textures
                    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

                    // Load input bitmap

                    try {
                    //load Bitmap from previous activity
    myuri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("uri"));

        Bitmap bitmap=new BitmapWorkerTask().execute(myuri).get();
                    mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                    mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                    mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

                    // Upload to texture
                    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
                    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

                    // Set texture parameters
                    GLToolbox.initTexParams();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


           private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        } else {
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }






 //this method decodes the bitmap
                public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Uri uri, int reqWidth,
                        int reqHeight) {

                    Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    currentDisplay.getSize(size);

                    dw = size.x;
                    dh = size.y;

                    // Load up the image's dimensions not the image itself
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    try {
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                                .openInputStream(uri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth
                            / (float) reqWidth);
                    int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight
                            / (float) reqHeight);

                    if (heightRatio > 1 && widthRatio > 1) {
                        if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
                        } else {
                            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                        }

                        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                        try {
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                                    .openInputStream(uri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }

                    }
                    return bmp;

                }



                class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap> {

                    Uri uri;

                    @Override
                    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... imageuri) {

                        uri = imageuri[0];
                        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(uri, dw, dh);
                    }

                }

            }
```

I've tried refactoring here and there,but without any success...any help is appreciated,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AsyncTask`, you need to add the `onPostExecute(...)` method to handle the value returned from `doInBackground()`. You can find an example of a complete `AsynTask` implementation in this SO question:

[Android AsyncTask example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of places in your `decodeSampledBitmap()` method where exceptions are caught but you don't log them or print the stack trace of the exception.  I would do something like `e.printStackTrace()` in those blocks just to help debug and make sure an exception isn't being thrown.

Also, it's a good idea to decode the bitmap off of the UI thread (you don't want to risk an ANR while decoding), but I'm not sure it will speed up the time it takes to decode and display your images.

Comment: you're right, unfortunately it doesnt speed up, there arent any exceptions being thrown up from there,but ill keep that in mind